# Escaping quotes from expressionengine's output for Javascript

Tags: quotes, expressionengine

I have the following in one of my EE templates:

```
<!-- Set up dynamic js array for notebook data -->
<script type="text/javascript">
notebooks = [{exp:channel:entries channel="product-notebooks" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}
{"entry_id": "{entry_id}",
"notebook_covertext": "{notebook-covertext}",
"notebook_image": "{notebook-image}"}
,{/exp:channel:entries}
]
</script>
```

Basically I'd like {notebook-covertext} to escape or htmlentity-ize the content.. anyone know how I can achieve this?

Cheers,
John.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [this hidden config variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#protect-javascript)

```
$config['protect_javascript'] = 'y';
```

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](https://github.com/mhulse/mah_eencode) should do the trick.

```
"notebook_covertext": "{exp:mah_eencode}{notebook-covertext}{/exp:mah_eencode}",
```